# How to highlight specific text shown in a multiline textbox?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, highlighting

In my application i have to highlight some text (incorrect words) which are returned by an API to show in a multiline textbox.
How to highlight specific words in the string returned by an API.
My code is

```
 ServiceReference1.GetTextSoapClient c = new GetTextSoapClient();
 string text = c.GetTextFromImage(@"D:\Files\OCR\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
 txtContent.Text = text;
 List<string> list_Words = GetWords(text);
```

How to highlight specific words in text.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to select a word in a multiline text box you must first find the word :

```
int start_index = textBox1.Text.IndexOf("word");
```

then highlight it :

```
textBox1.Focus();
textBox1.Select(start_index, word lenght);
```

but if you want to select multiple words and change the color , highlight background etc.... you must use rich text box